# Format String Direct Parameter Behavior

Tags: exploit, arm64

I am investigating a format string vulnerability on arm64 (linked against musl libc), and am encountering some odd behavior while debugging the output.

From the decompilation, the program has a classic format string vulnerability that boils down to:

```
fprintf(stdout, user_controlled_data);
```

Using repetitive format specifiers (e.g. `%p%p%p%p`), I can dump massive swaths of memory by including thousands of these characters. That works as expected.

The problem arises when I try direct parameter access. For some reason, `%1$p` works but not `%2$p`, but 3 up to about 12 works, and everything I've tried after that fails. By "fails", I mean no values are printed, except the newline automatically added to my string earlier in code is eaten somehow. In the debugger, `fprintf` returns -1, and `errno` is set to 0x16, which I believe is EINVAL.

For this particular scenario, I need the ability to read/write a particular stack offset in the thousands. But I cannot print it to confirm since direct parameter access does not work. I *can* see the target parameter by using repeated characters, but I need direct parameters to work going forward due to other constraints.

Now, I understand this is in "undefined behavior" territory, but I compiled a vulnerable test binary (statically linked against Glibc, I should probably try against musl) on the system that works as expected with no issues (e.g. `%9000$p` prints something).

Is there something that would cause this behavior, or something I am missing? I can provide further information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting the question, I started to think about the difference in the libc I was using. I compiled the basic test binary again but with musl, and also saw the unexpected behavior there. This seems to be due to the `printf` implementation in [musl](https://github.com/bminor/musl/blob/master/src/stdio/vfprintf.c#L464):

```
        if (isdigit(s[1]) && s[2]=='$') {
            l10n=1;
            argpos = s[1]-'0';
            s+=3;
        }
```

It only uses direct parameters if there is exactly one digit following the `%`, followed by a `$`. This explains why I was unable to print any larger stack offsets.

**Edit:** This seems [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html)-compliant:

> "%n$", where n is a decimal integer in the range [1,{NL_ARGMAX}], giving the
>   position of the argument in the argument list.

Then, looking at [the definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/limits.h.html) of NL_ARGMAX:

> NL_ARGMAX
>
> Maximum value of digit in calls to the printf() and scanf()
>   functions. Minimum Acceptable Value: 9

So it appears that the implementation is indeed following the standard by allowing the minimum value of 9, which is certainly inconvenient for writing compact format string exploits.

Comment: The author of musl makes a point of sticking to the word of the standards, so perhaps you should consult those. It's also possible you found a defect in the code, though.